# Electrum 2.7.9 setup never went through the password and seed setup, now I can't send coins

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery

I installed the Electrum 2.7.9 wallet and it never went through the password and seed setup. I ended up with a default standard wallet. I then uninstalled the Electrum wallet and then reinstalled it. Once again it didn't go through any password or seed setup and I had a default standard wallet on my pc. I made the dumb decision, because I am totally new at this, to go ahead and send my bitcoins from my coinbin wallet to the address associated with the standard default wallet and now I can't send anything because it wants a password. Please help!

Comment: You entered the password it asks you for when you created the wallet. If you don't remember the password, you need the seed. You were asked to write it down when creating the wallet. Do you have it?

Comment: For the future, I would really strongly recommend against putting in Bitcoin any money that you can't afford to lose.

Comment: I'm sorry but didn't you read my post? The setup of the Electrum wallet didn't ask for or walk me through the setup of password or seed. I also think your recommendation is painfully obvious. I have not technically lost the bitcoins, they are in my default wallet I just can't access them. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Okay I have now figured out how to setup a new Electrum wallet from my default Electrum wallet. My bitcoins are still on an address associated with my default Electrum wallet and when I try to send to my standard Electrum wallet the default wallet is asking for a password which was never setup. The default wallet doesn't have a password. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, without either password or seed, an Electrum wallet is not recoverable.

But let's reconstruct how it happened and see what you perhaps could do:

Electrum doesn't create a new wallet during setup only when there is already an Electrum wallet on the system.

It therefore seems likely that you or another user of your computer had installed Electrum on that computer before. Perhaps you should try to figure out if the seed and/or password was recorded back then, but you had forgotten about it. Else, you should first try likely passwords.

If you cannot make any progress with that, you might want to consider getting in touch with https://walletrecoveryservices.com/. I cannot personally vouch for them, but they appear to have helped a load of people in the past. They may be able to help you recover your password, if you have any idea about what you may have used.

<sup>Thanks to #electrum on freenode for most of the above information.</sup>